# Universal cross-platform syntax URL parameters directions travel type transit departure time

Tags: directions, google-maps-urls

My app is using the universal maps URL to open a local transit route map.

I have no problem getting the map I want using something like:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=42.352312,-122.869691&destination=42.324418,-122.871534&travelmode=transit

I would like to add departure time to the url, but having no luck getting the map to show the route for the requested departure.

From what I can gather, the departure time parameter is 'departure_time', and the value is in Julian seconds.

I was hoping the following URL would give me the route that departed around 9:30am PST June 6 2018:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=42.352312,-122.869691&destination=42.324418,-122.871534&travelmode=transit&departure_time=32503647540

But no matter what time I specify, it returns a route at the current time, not the time I requested.

So, what am I doing wrong?

I figure either the parameter name is wrong (I also tried 'departuretime'), or my julian date calculation is wrong, or departure time is not supported.

Anybody?

Comment: This information is not currently supported by the Maps URLs. But, we have a feature request in Google Issue Tracker to add this functionality. To register your interest in this issue, please visit the Issue Tracker at the link below, and star the issue. This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. You can view and star the issue here: [Issue 160453518](https://issuetracker.google.com/160453518)